# Ubuntu 18.04 stalls on shutdown. [Lenovo Legion Y520]

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, 18.04, shutdown

whenever I try to restart or shutdown my laptop it freezes up completely and never continues with the process.

Things I have attempted:

- Setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force apm=power_off"` in /etc/default/grub
- Adding `apm power_off=1` to /etc/modules
- Updating everything fully
- Installing Nvidia graphic drivers

This doesn't only occur on shutdown, it sometimes stalls from regular use.

I also went through the logs and here is everything in the important section: 
 [Screenshot of logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKgY3.png)

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was planning on just marking [@Bernard's](https://askubuntu.com/users/398808/bernard-wei) answer as correct when it started working, but then I wanted to go one step further and show y'all the steps I did to fix it while still using GDM3.

The first thing I did was undo all of my previous attempts including the Nvidia driver, and I noticed that without the Nvidia driver it did shutdown properly somehow. The odd part is, later on I figured out that secure boot was preventing Nvidia's driver to even enable so I'm not sure what happened on that front.

After this realization, I properly loaded in Nvidia's driver and reached the same issue [Bernard](https://askubuntu.com/users/398808/bernard-wei) probably experienced.

On shutdown I received a warning saying "Failed to connect to lvmetad", which cancelled the shutdown and looped to the login screen.

After some Googling I came across [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/warning-failed-to-connect-to-lvmetad-what-to-do-4175619007/#post5792493) post on linuxquestions.org which told me the following step.

> Originally Posted by AwesomeMachine  [View Post](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/warning-failed-to-connect-to-lvmetad-what-to-do-4175619007/#post5789501)
>   Try first to disable lvmetad from /etc/lvm/lvm.conf and set use_lvmetad = 0. Use a live CD if you have to.

This allowed me to shutdown normally, but there is still a message on startup which I will deal with in the future.

The reason I made this post, is due to my experience with the hassle regarding Nvidia drivers and Ubuntu, I want to make it easier for the next person who comes around, hopefully this helps.

Thank you again [Bernard](https://askubuntu.com/users/398808/bernard-wei) for pointing me in the right direction

Edit: Solved the lvmetad error showing on startup by running

> sudo update-initramfs -k *KERNEL_VERSION* -u ; sync

after changing the value in the config. Ps: replace *KERNAL_VERSION* with your kernal version

Comment: possibly the diffence is that Yoga 720 has the  GTX 1050 as to the GTX 1060 on the Y520. I didn't use LVM either but will keep your post in mind if I ever enable it. Glad you found a solution, cheers.

Comment: My Lenovo Legion Y520 actually uses a 1050-TI Mobile

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the greeter back to lightdm,

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

It might be the thing that fixed my problem, I have a Yoga 720. I also have changed the display driver to nvidia proprietary and update everything to the latest.

Comment: I realized while installing the Nvidia drivers that it enables Secure boot, can that possibly also attribute to the cause?

As for the lightdm, it appears to not be installed "dpkg-query: package 'lightdm' is not installed and no information is available"

Comment: Secure boot shouldn't be the cause of the lock-up, as I have it enabled in my system bios without any issue. LightDM was used by many Ubuntu releases for some time until 18.04, which switch back to the gnome greeter. If you want to use light dm, you need to install it first as 18.04 by default comes with gnome greeter. After you have installed the lightdm package, you can then use the dpkg-reconfigure to select lightdm. Not guarantee this is the source of your problem of course, thought it might be something you can try.